# Show dynamic number of colums in ListView/DataGrid using WPF Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datagrid

I have a question that confuses me a little bit: I want to ask about dynamic columns building in ListView/DataGrid in WPF(Xaml). I mean, the number of columns is not determined and can change over time. For example:

```
public class LocalizationModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<LocalizationCell> Translation { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizationCell
{
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
    public LocalizationCell(CultureInfo culture, string translation)
    {
        Culture = culture;
        Translation = translation;
    }
}
```

and in ViewModel i have the next property:

```
  public IEnumerable<LocalizationModel> LocalizationList
    {
        get => _localizationList;
        set => Set(ref _localizationList, value);
    }
```

In that way i try to hold information about key and local value.

On my View i want to show this collection using ListView or DataGrid with the possibility to change localization value. I need some approach to build columns dynamically using XAML, for example:

|Key  |English  |Denmark  |Spanish|...

Answer (score 0):

XAML is not a programming language. It is a *markup* language that has no support to add columns dynamically.

You could either add columns to the `DataGrid` programmatically, in the code-behind of the view, or you could set or bind the `ItemsSource` to a `DataTable` to which you can add columns dynamically.